# Importing SimpleAuth ForSquareWeb - 9 build time errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, cocoapods

I'm relatively new to objective-c and hardly know much of swift.

I've been trying to make an app which will implement simpleAuth in order to create a link to the ForsquareWeb API.

I'm using cocoapods and have imported the SimpleAuth related files into my product.

Every file seems to be fine except the SimpleAuth target, specifically the SimpleAuthForSquareWebProvider.m file. This is what the file itself looks like;

```
//
//  SimpleAuthFoursquareWebProvider.m
//  SimpleAuth
//
//  Created by Julien Seren-Rosso on 23/01/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Byliner, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SimpleAuthFoursquareWebProvider.h"
#import "SimpleAuthFoursquareWebLoginViewController.h"

#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
#import "UIViewController+SimpleAuthAdditions.h"

@implementation SimpleAuthFoursquareWebProvider

#pragma mark - SimpleAuthProvider

+ (NSString *)type {
return @"foursquare-web";
}

+ (NSDictionary *)defaultOptions {

// Default present block
SimpleAuthInterfaceHandler presentBlock = ^(UIViewController *controller) {
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    navigation.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    UIViewController *presented = [UIViewController SimpleAuth_presentedViewController];
    [presented presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
};

// Default dismiss block
SimpleAuthInterfaceHandler dismissBlock = ^(id controller) {
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[super defaultOptions]];
options[SimpleAuthPresentInterfaceBlockKey] = presentBlock;
options[SimpleAuthDismissInterfaceBlockKey] = dismissBlock;
return options;
}

- (void)authorizeWithCompletion:(SimpleAuthRequestHandler)completion {
[[[self accessToken]
 flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSString *response) {
     NSArray *signals = @[
         [self accountWithAccessToken:response],
         [RACSignal return:response]
     ];
     return [self rac_liftSelector:@selector(dictionaryWithAccount:accessToken:) withSignalsFromArray:signals];
 }]
 subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *response) {
     completion(response, nil);
 }
 error:^(NSError *error) {
     completion(nil, error);
 }];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (RACSignal *)accessToken {
return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SimpleAuthFoursquareWebLoginViewController *login = [[SimpleAuthFoursquareWebLoginViewController alloc] initWithOptions:self.options];
        login.completion = ^(UIViewController *login, NSURL *URL, NSError *error) {
            SimpleAuthInterfaceHandler dismissBlock = self.options[SimpleAuthDismissInterfaceBlockKey];
            dismissBlock(login);

            // Parse URL
            NSString *fragment = [URL fragment];
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [CMDQueryStringSerialization dictionaryWithQueryString:fragment];
            NSString *token = dictionary[@"access_token"];

            // Check for error
            if (![token length]) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
                return;
            }

            // Send completion
            [subscriber sendNext:token];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        };

        SimpleAuthInterfaceHandler block = self.options[SimpleAuthPresentInterfaceBlockKey];
        block(login);
    });
    return nil;
}];
}


- (RACSignal *)accountWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"oauth_token" : accessToken };
    NSString *query = [CMDQueryStringSerialization queryStringWithDictionary:parameters];
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?v=20140210&%@", query];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:self.operationQueue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
         NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 99)];
         NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
         if ([indexSet containsIndex:statusCode] && data) {
             NSError *parseError = nil;
             NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];
             if (dictionary) {
                 [subscriber sendNext:dictionary];
                 [subscriber sendCompleted];
             }
             else {
                 [subscriber sendError:parseError];
             }
         }
         else {
             [subscriber sendError:connectionError];
         }
     }];
    return nil;
}];
}


- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithAccount:(NSDictionary *)account accessToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDictionary *userData = account[@"response"][@"user"];

// Provider
dictionary[@"provider"] = [[self class] type];

// Credentials
dictionary[@"credentials"] = @{
                               @"token" : accessToken
                               };

// User ID
dictionary[@"uid"] = userData[@"id"];

// Raw response
dictionary[@"extra"] = @{
                         @"raw_info" : userData
                         };

// User info
NSMutableDictionary *user = [NSMutableDictionary new];
if (userData[@"contact"][@"email"]) {
    user[@"email"] = userData[@"contact"][@"email"];
}

if (userData[@"firstName"]) {
    user[@"first_name"] = userData[@"firstName"];
}

if (userData[@"lastName"]) {
    user[@"last_name"] = userData[@"lastName"];
}

user[@"name"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", user[@"first_name"], user[@"last_name"]];

user[@"gender"] = userData[@"gender"];

if ([userData[@"photo"] isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
    user[@"image"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@500x500%@", userData[@"photo"][@"prefix"], userData[@"photo"][@"suffix"]];
} else if ([userData[@"photo"] isKindOfClass:NSString.class]) {
    user[@"image"] = userData[@"photo"];
}

if (userData[@"photo"]) {
    user[@"photo"] = userData[@"photo"];
}
if (userData[@"homeCity"]) {
    NSString *homecity = [[userData[@"homeCity"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] firstObject];
    user[@"location"] = homecity;
}
user[@"urls"] = @{
                  @"Foursquare" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://foursquare.com/user/%@", userData[@"id"]],
                  };
dictionary[@"info"] = user;

return dictionary;
}


@end
```

I think it would be easier to show you just a screen shot of the errors and where they're arising in the code itself;

[image: Errors in implementation file]

I would really appreciate some insight into where the problem lies. I'm not sure why many of the errors say use of undeclared identifiers, are the imported files not correct?

**After trying to re-install the pod file as it was suggested a class hadn't been installed I still have the same problem. Here are screen shots of my podfile and the terminals output when installing the pods;**

[image: Podfile]
[image: Terminal]

**I just used the Cocoapods application rather than terminal. I got additional information when clicking install.**

"[!] The `dPicDid [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-dPicDid/Pods-dPicDid.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `dPicDid [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-dPicDid/Pods-dPicDid.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)`flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: RACSignal missing you need to install pod again

Comment: Thanks for the response Siddhesh. Would I have to delete all pod files and re-install it through the terminal as I have previously done?

Comment: No just use command pod install

Comment: Hi Siddhesh, I've tried to reinstall the pods through the terminal, however the problem still arises where xcode will not accept RACSignal as a term? I've added some screen shots of the podfile and the terminal incase I've done something wrong?

Comment: I think this is because of swift library in objective c project. You can use Bridging-Header to add swift  library.

Comment: Sorry Siddhesh I'm not sure what Bridging-Header is in order to add swift library, could you please elaborate :)?

Comment: Bridging-header will gives you Swift’s file or swift cocoa compatibility with Objective C